# Build go-ethereum source code

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I wanted to build go-ethereum source code in my local side and test it in geth.
I have followed up the instructions in the github go-ethereum as it is.
However, I have got fail with some errors when I try command to build as below.

go-ethereum>**go install -v github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth**

Is there any ways to build go-ethereum source code on either windows or ubuntu?
I have tested it in both windows10 and Ubuntu18.04 with go version 1.13.4.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: My build command is as follows.     C:\Users\Jon\go\src\github.com\ethereum\go-ethereum>go install -v github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/cmd/geth

Comment: C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/oledlg.h:428:3: error: unknown type name 'interface'   ECLARE_INTERFACE_(IOleUILinkContainerW,IUnknown) { C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/oledlg.h:428:3: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '{' token   DECLARE_INTERFACE_(IOleUILinkContainerW,IUnknown) {
 In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/setupapi.h:27:0, from ..\..\..\..\pkg\mod\github.com\karalabe\usb@v0.0.0-20190919080040-51dc0efba356\libusb\libusb/os/windows_winusb.c:29,from

Comment: Errors are like above which are not whole error messages. This errors are same from on both windows10 and Ubuntu18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those [instructions](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/install-and-build/installing-geth) work for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm assuming it's something to do with your Go installation (or a missing/out-of-date C compiler?).

Another, `make`-based, method (which again works for me on Ubuntu) is the following:

- `git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum`
- Install the latest version of Go
- `sudo apt-get install -y build-essential`
- `cd go-ethereum`
- `make geth`

Comment: I have tried the command "make geth", but it does not work. How does it work the make commands?

Comment: I have successfully build on Mac for the same source code, but I have error on header files in both windows and ubuntu.

Comment: It looks like you might be hitting this issue: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/20093